# Why do I get wildly different file transfer speeds via SATA

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

Single windows PC, with 4 internal HDD's and one external HDD connected via e-SATA cable. My mobo is the older SATA 3, not SATA 6.

I get wildly different file transfer speeds when transferring from one internal HDD to another, or from internal to the external e-SATA drive.

example: in doing backups, one large single file to the external: I was getting a very slow 16 to 24 MB/s. a bit later it was doing another larger single file (a linux ISO) to the external hdd, and it was racing along at 125 MB/s. Sometimes I'll see 55 MB/s, other times 90MB/s.

I understand that doing a collection of many tiny files can slow the transfer rate, but what accounts for the huge variance (nearly 8x) in doing these single large files?

Comment: [I use this program](https://rejzor.wordpress.com/powerdefrag/) to defrag my drives, it does a much better job that the built in defragger in windows, it uses the sysinternals program contig to get the job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how a physical harddrive works. When data is written to the harddrive, the partition table stores for each file where the data is stored.

It does this as follows: It looks up the first available free spot, and starts writing there. When the file is bigger than that space, it will stop writing there, and make a note in the partition table where part of that file is stored. Then it searches for the next available free space and starts writing there. Due to this way, your harddrive will become fragmented. NTFS has techniques to make it less fragmented, but it still will get fragmented.

Because of this, looking up big files is likely causing your harddrive head to go all over the place as it has to access the file all over the place, slowing down the reading.

EDIT: also, forgot to mention, when you remove a file, the free space is not reordered, just flagged as free space. So deleting small files creates small gaps that large files will be written to. NTFS will try to minimize this as much as possible, but especially with really large files, it can't always do that.

Comment: Since I posted, I've been doing some testing, and your reply makes a lot of sense. I found that I could replicate the very slow (16 MB/s) transfer by copying the same file again that was slow before. It is a rather new file, so it is probably spread out on the drive due to fragmentation. I will now defrag that drive, and retest that file. Thanks!

Comment: update: after defragmenting that drive where the slowly transferring file resided, it's transfer speed improved from 16 MB/s, to 91 MB/s.